How can I see sqlite3's index usage statistics?
I have a sqlite3 database. Other RDBMS have allowed me to view index usage statistics, and therefore to clear out indexes that the optimizer is not using for my queries. How can I do this with sqlite3?

That's not anything SQLite tracks.

You can use EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN to find out what indexes a particular query uses and make a list of them...

Thanks, I was looking for automatic tracking since I have many regular queries, but you've answered the question, sadly! Feel free to make that an answer.

Successfully automated EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN against all my views, which did the vast majority of what I needed - thanks.
